# tar fills up my HDD

Tags: buffer, tar

I'm trying to tar a pretty big folder (~11GB) and while taring, my VM crashes because its disk is full. But... I still have plenty of room available on all disks but `/`

```
$ sudo df -h
File system        Size    Used    Avail. Used% Mount on
udev               3,9G       0  3,9G   0% /dev
tmpfs              799M    9,3M  790M   2% /run
/dev/sda1          9,1G    3,1G  5,6G  36% /
/dev/sda2           69G     37G   29G  57% /home
/dev/sdb1          197G     87G  100G  47% /docker
```

I assume tar is buffering somewhere on `/` and fulfil it before my OS crashes. By the way, I have no idea on how to prevent this. Do you guy have any idea?

Cheers,
Olivier

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tar normally builds the archive in the current directory, as a hidden file. Try cd'ing to one of your larger partition mounting points and taring from there to see if it makes a difference. You may also be running out of innodes:

[No Space Left on Device, Running out of Innodes](https://www.ivankuznetsov.com/2010/02/no-space-left-on-device-running-out-of-inodes.html)

I ran into a similar problem with a server because of too many small files. While you have plenty of free space left, you might run into this issue.

Comment: You made my day. In fact, it was not related directly to iNodes but monitoring both inodes & disk space, with none being full, you helped me realize that it might come from outside. The disk on which the VM is running was simply full... Now it works. Thanks a lot.